# What is the maximum volume of lebesgue measurable set $A\subseteq [0,6]$ such that...

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, volume

$\text{I came accross an interesting question:}$

$ $

$\text{What is the maximum volume of a lebesgue measurable set } A\subseteq[0,6]^2 \text{ such that: }$

$A \cap \bigl(A+\binom 12\bigl)=\emptyset $

$\text{I got only to } 5\pi \text{  but the answer is 24. What am I missing?}$

Comment: Could you say a rough word on how you got $5\pi$?

Comment: What if $A=[0,6]^2\setminus \{(1,2)\}$? Maybe you mean $\cup$ instead of $\cap$?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Sorry I mistranslated the question, see edit :)

Comment: It makes more sense now, but still... $5\pi$?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I just thought about the open circle: $(x-a)^2+(x-b)^2 < 5$ that is inside $[0,6]^2$. I mean, if (a+1, b+2) > (x,y) for (x,y) $\in$ A

Comment: If your notation means $A+(1,2)$, 24 is easy to see, just take the two (open) rectangles of length 6 and height 2 on the top and bottom of the square $[0,6]^2$. This is $A$.

Comment: @Xiao haha I coudn't I've seen that?? I went too far ^_^; Thanks!